# Simple d3 bar graph doesn't show up

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, bar-chart

This is the simple bar graph that I am trying out. But nothing is showing up.

```
var data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];
var chart = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
 .attr("class", "chart")
 .attr("width", 420)
 .attr("height", 20 * data.length);

var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(data)]).range([0, 420]);

chart.selectAll("svg:rect")
 .data(data)
 .enter().append("svg:rect")
 .attr("y", function(d, i) { return i * 20; })
 .attr("width", x)
 .attr("height", 20)
```

If I use `rect` instead of `svg:rect` the rects get created as I can see in console but I cannot see it in browser.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to add some CSS to fill/colour the rectangles. You can also set this using `.style("fill", "red")` for example.

Comment: Its already done in CSS, But its not showing up. also If I move my mouse over the `rect` node in console window it will highlight the node.but no node is being highlighted too

Comment: Ah, spotted it. Change the line where you set the width to `.attr("width", function(d) { return x(d); })`.

Comment: You also need to change the svg:rect in the selectAll call to just rect as you suggest in the edit.

Comment: But why would `svg:rect` not work ? and even if I change it to `rect` It doesn't show Up.

Comment: I thought you wanted it to work :P D3 uses CSS3 selectors -- check out the [standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) to see what's allowed and what isn't.

Comment: How this relates with this problem ?

Comment: Your argument to `selectAll` is a CSS3 selector. You can't use `svg:rect` in there.

Comment: Selectors don't support namespaces, so you can't `selectAll("svg:rect")`. (The syntax would be `selectAll("svg|rect")`, but even that isn't supported by most browsers.) Recent versions of D3 don't require namespaces for creating elements, so you can now `append("rect")`, too. I recommend not using namespaces.